# Partitioning in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, gparted

No sound, so as suggested I upgraded to this version. Still no sound and thanks to NB seems sound is out of the question. Awhile back I downloaded gparted-live-0.7. but when i open it does not give me a workable interface.

Answer (score 0):

Try gpated from the live dvd you installed from, if that fails try downloading the live cd version of gparted and partition it that way.
 It sounds like you have not got the full downloaded dvd, try reinstalling missing or non working software from site, with package manager,you may have to uninstall the program before reinstall.-hope this works for the partition and sound.